# Theano get unique values in a tensor

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, enthought, theano

I have a tensor which I convert into a vector by flattening, now I want to remove the duplicate values in this vector. How can I do this? What is equivalent for numpy.unique() in theano?

```
x1 = T.itensor3('x1')
y1 = T.flatten(x1)
#z1 = T.unique() How do I do this?

For e.g. my tensor may be : [1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,1,3,4]
and I want : [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: this is now available in Theano: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/extra_ops.html#theano.tensor.extra_ops.Unique

This question was also asked on theano-user mailing list. The conclusion is that this is one of the function NumPy function that isn't wrapped in Theano. As he don't need the grad, it can be rapidly wrapped. Here is an example who expect the outputs to be the same as the input.

```
from theano.compile.ops import as_op


@as_op(itypes=[theano.tensor.imatrix],
       otypes=[theano.tensor.imatrix])
def numpy_unique(a):
    return numpy.unique(a)
```

More doc about as_op is available here: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/extending_theano.html#as-op-example